# PHP '5 out of 10' Helpfulness counter question

Tags: php, sql, count

I have been searching the web and stackoverflow for 60 minutes but have yet to find a solution/tutorial on here or the web explaining how I can do an 45 out of 50 helpful system in an efficient manner!

Better explanation: I'm experimenting with PHP and am trying to make a helpful system i.e. '5 out of 10 found this article helpful' but am struggling to figure out the best way to approach it and I feel my way is a bit bulky and their might be simpler ways!

My table:

```
| id | user_id | opinion | type | type_id | ip | date
---------------------------------------------
  1     2            1        1      1       ::1  dd/mm/yy
```

**My Way:**
My way is count all of the data for this type_id to get the 'out of total' and then to get the amount look for the '1' (yes) and count all of those! I'm just wondering if there is a faster way instead of me doing two count functions. (all about optimising)

My Current Count Code to get the outcome I want is this:

```
public function getTotalHelpfulness($id)
{
    $bind = [':id' => $id];
    $results = $this->db->select('helpful','type = 1 AND type_id = :id', $bind);
    $totalRows = count($results);
    if($results === FALSE){ $totalRows = '0'; }
    return $totalRows;
}
public function getYesHelpfulness($id)
{
    $bind = [':id' => $id];
    $results = $this->db->select('helpful',
      'opinion = 1 AND type = 1 AND type_id = :id', $bind);
    $totalRows = count($results);
    if($results === FALSE){ $totalRows = '0'; }
    return $totalRows;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What's your currently code?

Comment: @D-Shih I added my counting code at top which i'm currently using to get my desired result, i'm simply wondering if there is a better way to do it (more efficient) Thanks

Comment: I think it is better to create a field on the element to be voted and a field that allows the user to vote 1 time. Then it depends on what you have to do precisely. In that way you wouldn't need to count, but only to extract the value from the db

Comment: @Squalo thanks. What i'm trying to achieve is a Zendesk style counter where the user can say whether they found it helpful or not and just wan tto find the best way to do it as I can't find anything online! And the user can only vote once as it records their user_pin

Comment: @AchmedZuzali From what I understand, then you just need to add a field to the element to be voted. after which you allow the user to add +1 to that field and prohibit subsequent votes

Comment: @Squalo so a counter in a row where i do an update query of counter = counter + 1 ?? and then another table for the user_id and ip addresses? Thanks

Comment: Yes, counter = counter +1. After you need to store the items voted by the users: I think it is better to enter the id of users who voted in the row of the element to be voted. Because in the future that element could be deleted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179718/discussion-between-achmed-zuzali-and-squalo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just my two cents since I see no other answers. In plain SQL I would do:

```
select
    sum(case when opinion = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as positive_votes,
    count(*) as total
  from my_table
  where type = 1 and type_id = :id;
```

This query performs a single run over all rows and generates two counts: positive votes, and total votes.